# BIRT Report Designer empty DataSet scripting

Tags: jdbc, firebird, birt, report-designer, jaybird

I am using BIRT Report Designer 4.4.0 and I kept getting the error message

> org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Cannot fetch the next data row. org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: Cannot move down to next row in the result set. SQL error #1:The result set is closed ; org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: The result set is closed

when BIRT tried to fetch a row from a dataset which I knew was empty. I found that this is a common issue with BIRT and tried to prevent the empty dataset with a beforeOpen script on the dataset is in which I probably did wrong because it didn't work.
I created a vars["item"] and wanted to count how often OnFetch was called.

BeforeOpen:

```java
vars["item"] = 0;
```

OnFetch:

```java
vars["item"]++;
```

BeforeClose:

```java
if (vars["item"] == 0)
{
  row[0] = "0";
}
```

which doesn't work because there is no row[0] I guess.

When I edited the queryText of the dataset to just

```sql
SELECT "0" from kontrolle
```

which should definitely produce a dataset, I still got the same "Cannot fetch the next data row" error!

The design looks roughly like this:

```xml
<table>
   <table>
      <table> here is the dataset in question
      </table>
   </table>
</table>
```

The second table is bound to the first table by only one parameter, however, the third table has two parameter bindings to the second one.

Hope the explanation was good enough and someone can provide a solution.

Comment: Which Jaybird version are you using?

Comment: I am using Jaybird 2.2.7

Comment: What happens if you add `defaultResultSetHoldable=true` to the connection properties (eg in the JDBC url)?

Comment: I don't know if I should be frustrated or overly happy that just adding this did the trick! Thanks so much! I removed the scripting thing though.

Comment: Could you maybe a few sentences and explain to me what it does and I can rate your answer as my solution

Comment: Well, I maintain Jaybird, and unfortunately it looks like a lot of applications expect holdable result sets without explicitly asking for them. So this usually does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented before, add `defaultResultSetHoldable=true` to the connection properties (eg in the JDBC url). This instructs Jaybird to create connections with holdable result sets by default (the equivalent to calling `connection.setHoldability(ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT)` in code).

I don't really know BIRT, so this is nothing more than an educated guess to the cause:

1. It could expect holdable result sets without explicitly asking or checking for them, and commits after opening the result sets (in Jaybird by default result sets are closed on a commit)
2. BIRT could use `autoCommit=true` (the default), but doesn't expect result sets to be closed on execution of another statement on the same connection (this causes a close of resources like result sets, and a commit as specified by the JDBC standard; in some aspects this is a specialization of point 1).